# How to get the sum of specific entry in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example if I want to get the agent codes whose sum of order amount is greater than 4000. what query should I use in mysql?

My table is as follows: 
[image: k]

Comment: It would be better to copy the database text and copy is as code. Pictures of code constitutes poor formatting.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica poor formatting means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the AGENT_CODE in your query then following will help

`SELECT AGENT_CODE FROM yourTableName GROUP BY AGENT_CODE HAVING SUM(ORD_AMOUNT)>4000;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT AGENT_CODE, 
       SUM(ORD_AMOUNT) AS Total 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY AGENT_CODE
HAVING Total > 4000;
```

- You need to `GROUP BY` by the column Is not calculated, if not you will get only one row
- To filter data derived of a reducted function like **SUM** you will need to use `HAVING` through it's alias in this case `Total`

Also if you need yo filter by some column you can use the `WHERE` clausule between `From` and `GROUP...`

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.AGENT_CODE , a.TOTAL
from (
(select AGENT_CODE, sum(ORD_AMOUNT) as TOTAL from schema.table group by (AGENT_CODE)))a 
where a.TOTAL>4000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT AGENT_CODE, SUM(ORD_AMOUNT) As Order_Amount
FROM TableName
WHERE Total > 4000
GROUP BY AGENT_CODE;
```